# RegEx and PHP - How to match with a non mandatory parameter

Tags: php, regex, match

I am using this RegEx:

```
\s*((\w*\.*\s*)+[.*(\w)]+(?=\d{4}))(\d{4}\s*\,)*
```

And the goal is to match words with the last one that ends with a dot, follower with 4 digits ending with a comma.

This is a test.2014,

And it works fine. Now, I would like to add the possibility to have a whitespace (\s) between the "test." and "2014,", but the whitespace is not a mandatory parameter, it should be matched if there.

Could you please help me on how to add that to my regex? How can we set not mandatory parameters ?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `[.*(\w)]+` doesn't match what you think it does.

Comment: The regex matches `......` or `(.*(()...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this pattern

```
\s*((\w*\.*\s*)+[.*(\w)]+\s*(?=\d{4}))(\d{4}\s*\,)*
```

`\s*` there is a zero or more time space. I added it before date pattern

Or try:

```
\s*((\w*\.*\s*)+[.*(\w)]+(?=\s*\d{4}))(\s*\d{4}\s*\,)*
```

Comment: Thank you Victor. Could you please give more details on what you did?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple ways you can do this. You can use the question mark, an asterisk, or you can specify the range of viable occurrences as is shown in the table below.

```
Regular Expressions Quantifiers
*   0 or more
+   1 or more
?   0 or 1
{3} Exactly 3
{3,}    3 or more
{3,5}   3, 4 or 5

\s*((\w*\.*\s*)+[.*(\w)]+(\s+)(?=\d{4}))(\d{4}\s*\,)*
\s*((\w*\.*\s*)+[.*(\w)]+(\s*)(?=\d{4}))(\d{4}\s*\,)*
\s*((\w*\.*\s*)+[.*(\w)]+\s{0,1}(?=\d{4}))(\d{4}\s*\,)*
```

Comment: thanks, now that I've added multiple solutions, mind removing your comment?

Comment: I removed message. What does you meant about `mind`?

Comment: Milos, you may also find [Rubular](http://rubular.com/) helpful in parsing your regular expressions. If Rubular doesn't work for you, there are plenty of other helpful online regexp parsers.

Comment: Victor - "mind" is like saying, "would it trouble you to ...", or "would you please ...". I guess it really comes from the idea of asking someone to be mindful of your request - or something to that effect.

Answer (score 1):

> And the goal is to match words with the last one that ends with a dot,
>   follower with 4 digits ending with a comma

```
(?:\s*\w+)*\s*\w+\.\d{4},
```

> Now, I would like to add the possibility to have a whitespace (\s)
>   between the "test." and "2014,", but the whitespace is not a mandatory
>   parameter,

```
(?:\s*\w+)*\s*\w+\.\s*\d{4},
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`/\s*((\w*\.*\s*)+[.*(\w)]+(\s*)(?=\d{4}))(\d{4}\s*\,)*/`